# How to map wsdl using maven-jaxb2-plugin with name collision

Tags: java, binding, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I have a problem mapping a web service to Java POJO's because it contains two elements:

- `label1`
- `label_1`

When the plugin transforms it to java POJO's the underscores in the names are stripped, causing duplicate fields in the generated class.

> [ERROR] Error while generating code.Location [
>   file:/C:/PrivateWS/test-project/sources/target/wsdl/test.wsdl{12,94}].
>   com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId:
>   file:/C:/PrivateWS/test-project/sources/target/wsdl/test.wsdl;
>   lineNumber: 12; columnNumber: 94; Two declarations cause a collision
>   in the ObjectFactory class.

I've tried to use an external binding file to rename one of the elements to a different name but this fails. 
I've looked at a lot of different fora, but i cannot find any solution that seems to work. As far as I can see the property is not aknowledged and this causes following error.

> [ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [
>   file:/C:/PrivateWS/test-project/sources/target/classes/bindings.xjb{9,46}].
>   com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2; systemId:
>   file:/C:/PrivateWS/test-project/sources/target/classes/bindings.xjb;
>   lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 46; compiler was unable to honor this
>   property customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its
>   inconsistent with other bindings.

What am I doing wrong to make the rename of the field work?

Changing the wsdl is not an option, because it is a third party wsdl.

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.testproject</groupId>
<artifactId>testproject</artifactId>
<version>0.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-binding-file</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>bindings.xjb</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-wsdl-file</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/wsdl</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</directory>
                                <includes>
                                    <include>test.wsdl</include>
                                </includes>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.13.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>TestProject</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <generatePackage>com.testproject</generatePackage>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <schemaInclude>wsdl/test.wsdl</schemaInclude>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <bindingDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</bindingDirectory>
                <bindingIncludes>
                    <include>bindings.xjb</include>
                </bindingIncludes>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <schemaDirectory>${project.build.directory}</schemaDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

test.wsdl

```
<definitions name="HelloService"
         targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
         xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
         xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xsd:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl" elementFormDefault="unqualified" targetNamespace="http://www.examples.com/wsdl/HelloService.wsdl" version="1.0">
    <xsd:element name="requestType" type="tns:requestType"/>

    <xsd:complexType final="extension restriction" name="requestType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="label1" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element form="qualified" minOccurs="0" name="label_1" type="xsd:string"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>

<message name="SayHelloRequest">
    <part element="tns:requestType" name="parameters"/>
</message>

<message name="SayHelloResponse">
    <part name="greeting" type="xsd:string"/>
</message>

<portType name="Hello_PortType">
    <operation name="sayHello">
        <input message="tns:SayHelloRequest"/>
        <output message="tns:SayHelloResponse"/>
    </operation>
</portType>

<binding name="Hello_Binding" type="tns:Hello_PortType">
    <soap:binding style="rpc"
                  transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <operation name="sayHello">
        <soap:operation soapAction="sayHello"/>
        <input>
            <soap:body
                    encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                    namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
                    use="encoded"/>
        </input>

        <output>
            <soap:body
                    encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
                    namespace="urn:examples:helloservice"
                    use="encoded"/>
        </output>
    </operation>
</binding>

<service name="Hello_Service">
    <documentation>WSDL File for HelloService</documentation>
    <port binding="tns:Hello_Binding" name="Hello_Port">
        <soap:address
                location="http://www.examples.com/SayHello/"/>
    </port>
</service>
```

binding.xjb

```
<jxb:bindings
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="*">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:complexType[@name='requestType']" required="false">
        <jxb:bindings node=".//xs:element[@name='label_1']" required="false">
            <jxb:property name="label2"/>
        </jxb:bindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you set `underscoreBinding` and tried?

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="*">
    <jxb:globalBindings underscoreBinding="asCharInWord" />
</jxb:bindings>
```